# How to create dependency between activities of Pipeline for Azure Data Factory in Python

Tags: python, dependencies, azure-data-factory

In an Azure DataFactory pipeline, I try to make two CopyActivities run sequentially, i.e. first one copies data from blob to SQL table, THEN the second one copies the SQL table to another database.

I tried below code, but the result pipeline has no dependency built upon activities (checked in Azure UI from workflow diagram and JSON). When I run the pipeline, I got error message like below:
*"ErrorResponseException: The template validation failed: 'The 'runAfter' property of template action 'my second activity nameScope' at line '1' and column '22521' contains non-existent action. balababla...."*

Once I manually add the dependency in Azure UI, I can run the pipeline successfully.

I appreciate if someone could point me to example code (Python/C#/Powershell) or document.
My Python code:

```
    def createDataFactoryRectStage(self,  
                               aPipelineName, aActivityStageName, aActivityAcquireName,
                               aRectFileName, aRectDSName,
                               aStageTableName, aStageDSName,
                               aAcquireTableName, aAcquireDSName):
    adf_client = self.__getAdfClient()

    ds_blob = AzureBlobDataset(linked_service_name = LinkedServiceReference(AZURE_DATAFACTORY_LS_BLOB_RECT), 
                               folder_path=PRJ_AZURE_BLOB_PATH_RECT, 
                               file_name = aRectFileName,
                               format = {"type": "TextFormat",
                                         "columnDelimiter": ",",
                                         "rowDelimiter": "",
                                         "nullValue": "\\N",
                                         "treatEmptyAsNull": "true",
                                         "firstRowAsHeader": "true",
                                         "quoteChar": "\"",})    
    adf_client.datasets.create_or_update(AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP, AZURE_DATAFACTORY, aRectDSName, ds_blob)

    ds_stage= AzureSqlTableDataset(linked_service_name = LinkedServiceReference(AZURE_DATAFACTORY_LS_SQLDB_STAGE), 
                                   table_name='[dbo].[' + aStageTableName + ']')      
    adf_client.datasets.create_or_update(AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP, AZURE_DATAFACTORY, aStageDSName, ds_stage)

    ca_blob_to_stage = CopyActivity(aActivityStageName, 
                                    inputs=[DatasetReference(aRectDSName)], 
                                    outputs=[DatasetReference(aStageDSName)], 
                                    source= BlobSource(), 
                                    sink= SqlSink(write_batch_size = AZURE_SQL_WRITE_BATCH_SIZE))

    ds_acquire= AzureSqlTableDataset(linked_service_name = LinkedServiceReference(AZURE_DATAFACTORY_LS_SQLDB_ACQUIRE), 
                                     table_name='[dbo].[' + aAcquireTableName + ']')      
    adf_client.datasets.create_or_update(AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP, AZURE_DATAFACTORY, aAcquireDSName, ds_acquire)
    dep = ActivityDependency(ca_blob_to_stage, dependency_conditions =[DependencyCondition('Succeeded')])

    ca_stage_to_acquire = CopyActivity(aActivityAcquireName, 
                                       inputs=[DatasetReference(aStageDSName)], 
                                       outputs=[DatasetReference(aAcquireDSName)], 
                                       source= SqlSource(), 
                                       sink= SqlSink(write_batch_size = AZURE_SQL_WRITE_BATCH_SIZE),
                                       depends_on=[dep])

    p_obj = PipelineResource(activities=[ca_blob_to_stage, ca_stage_to_acquire], parameters={})

    return adf_client.pipelines.create_or_update(AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP, AZURE_DATAFACTORY, aPipelineName, p_obj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone comes to the same problem as this old question like I did, there is a subtle bug in the python code

changing dep to use the activity name, not a reference to the activity object made it work for me.

```
dep = ActivityDependency(aActivityStageName, dependency_conditions =[DependencyCondition('Succeeded')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in `C#` which basically does `Chaining activities` and chain activities in a sequence within a pipeline. Remember in ADFV1 we had to configure the output of an activity as an input of another activity to chain them and make them depend on each other.

Pipeline code snippet (notice the dependsOn property which makes sure that the second activity runs after the first activity has completed it's run successfully) -

```
static PipelineResource PipelineDefinition(DataFactoryManagementClient client) {
 Console.WriteLine("Creating pipeline " + pipelineName + "...");
 PipelineResource resource = new PipelineResource {
   Activities = new List < Activity > {
    new CopyActivity {
     Name = copyFromBlobToSQLActivity,
      Inputs = new List < DatasetReference > {
       new DatasetReference {
        ReferenceName = blobSourceDatasetName
       }
      },
      Outputs = new List<DatasetReference>
      {
       new DatasetReference {
        ReferenceName = sqlDatasetName
       }
      },
      Source = new BlobSource {},
      Sink = new SqlSink {}
    },
    new CopyActivity {
     Name = copyToSQLServerActivity,
      Inputs = new List < DatasetReference > {
       new DatasetReference {
        ReferenceName = sqlDatasetName
       }
      },
      Outputs = new List<DatasetReference>
      {
       new DatasetReference {
        ReferenceName = sqlDestinationDatasetName
       }
      },
      Source = new SqlSource {},
      Sink = new SqlSink {},
      DependsOn = new List < ActivityDependency > {
       new ActivityDependency {
        Activity = copyFromBlobToSQLActivity,
         DependencyConditions = new List < String > {
          "Succeeded"
         }
       }
      }
    }
   }
 };
 Console.WriteLine(SafeJsonConvert.SerializeObject(resource, client.SerializationSettings));
 return resource;
}
```

Do check the ADFV2 tutorial [here](https://opdhsblobprod01.blob.core.windows.net/contents/4a6d75bb3af747de838e6ccc97c5d978/1b9c613d0b759aa54550eb176ff987cd?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=VH6By15Uu2Qj70h2gL%2B%2F8%2B5rrnxIzVw6Ytv27blMjks%3D&st=2018-08-28T07%3A38%3A02Z&se=2018-08-29T07%3A48%3A02Z&sp=r) for a comprehensive explanation and more scenarios.

Comment: Thank you Abhishek. This C# snippet is exactly the same as my Python snippet above, except for its inline style. I actually used the ADFV2 Python example code to construct my snippet. I have no idea why my Python snippet did not set the dependency.  I actually tested the two CopyActivites separately, both of them can work. Did you check the JSON and diagram of your pipeline?